# Problems with Gameloop when using VSync in windowed mode

Tags: c#, sharpdx

I readed some articles about RenderLoop inside C# using SharpDX but all has the same problem.
Using this loops it's fine for rendering at V-Sync rate except when some events happens.
For example dragging the window or right clicking mouse over window bar(opening menu) will stop the Loop. There is a way to avoid this? I want(even not refreshing the control) a stable 60 FPS loop.
I am rendering on a Control(Panel) and i need this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OP has surely resolved this issue by now, but since there are no answers after 3 months, here is mine:

Don't use SharpDx **VSync** when running in a window -- it's not meant for that, and will certainly cause contention & deadlocks. VSync is only helpful when you own the entire screen.

Just present your swapChain and let the window manager show it when it can, and you'll get the highest frame rate you can feed.

This same thing bit me a while back, and although I didn't find the answer anywhere in the documentation, it's obvious when you think about it: it would be impossible for windows to manage the desktop if each window tried to coordinate with VSync independently.

```
bool vSync = false;     // vSync should not be used in windowed modes -- may cause UI deadlocks when resizing form windows
swapChain.Present(vSync ? 1 : 0, PresentFlags.None, new PresentParameters());    // requires v11.1
```